# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in a Service in a separate process

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

On ICS, I'm getting an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error when using UrlConnection - even though I'm making this request in a Service that runs on it's own process, and was called asyncronously to be done via Messenger.

Changing the StrictPolicy had no effect, I still get the error.

What can I do?

edit: this Service runs in a separate process - has a different pid and everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services still run on the main thread, as per the the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

Therefore for long running tasks (such as using a UrlConnection) you should either use something like an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or spawn a new Thread yourself.

Comment: This service runs in a separate process.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it runs in a separate process to your other activities or services - any code running directly in the service will still be executed in the main thread of that process. If you use IntentService instead, then a new Thread will automatically be created for you for code executed in onHandleIntent().

Comment: So you're saying that a task, running in a Timer of a service that's in a completely separate process from the main one - will affect the main processes UI thread?

I haven't noticed this behavior, my UI does not freeze while networking is happening...

Comment: No, it won't affect the main process UI thread. It has its own separate "main" thread - and as this separate process has no UI it won't adversely affect anything the user sees. However, accessing the network on this thread will still trigger the exception you are seeing - if you are targeting HC+, no network operations are allowed on the main thread of any process (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks for taking the time to explain. I guess I'll stick each one into a Thread then, and will be able to have them be done asyncronously while at it.

Comment: I've remembered that a Timer takes an argument to run in daemon mode - I had it off before. I suspect this would do away with the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Do the network stuff in a `Thread` there. this exception is thrown to prevent some problems, like the UI freezing (because of the network job, that may take time.)